# Generate xls file with zeros before number using APEX in Salesforce.com platform

Tags: excel, salesforce, apex

I need '0123' value in cell, but after generating xls it show only '123'.
It removes all zeros before number, but I want them inside cell.

Manually I can change cell format and then write any number with zeros at the beginning of the number. Maybe the solution will be generate xls file with cell format 'text'? But how change format cell in apex?

Comment: How are you creating the Excel file?  Are you using a utility or is this the Salesforce output of a report?

Comment: In VF I have the button. Action from this button refer to newVF by PageReference. I add contentType="application/x-excel;MyFile.xls" to apexPage of this newVF. Mainly I used help from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003176&type=1

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. In controller, before sending data to Visualforce page I wrap number in quotation marks and put equal sign before it, and store wrapped number as a String e.g.

```
="0123"
```

Then excel will keep it as text format, but as value show only '0123'.